# How to edit a protected cell range on Google Sheets with scripts

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-query

I have created a tracker to capture time automatically in the next cell when a cell is edited. And the time should be protected from being edited manually (through protected range). I have the below script but don't know how can I implement it on the sheet in which user's cannot edit the protected range but the script should.

```
function onEdit() {
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
        var r = s.getActiveCell();
        if( r.getColumn() == 3 ) { //checks the column
            var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
            //if( nextCell.getValue() !== '' ) //is empty?
            nextCell.setValue(new Date());
        }

        if( r.getColumn() == 5 ) { //checks the column
            var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
            //if( nextCell.getValue() !== '' ) //is empty?
            nextCell.setValue(new Date());
        }
    }
}
```

I want the script to run on the protected range when end user edits a cell before the protected range

The script works fine for me. But does not works for user's who don't have access to edit the protected range.